# load a custom css file in single page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Why Cant include the Custom Css File in post page (single page) ?

In Other Page can Include it( Such as woocommerce.php | archive.php )
But I Can Load in Single File !
Why Cant it ? Does the single page have any special restrictions?

In this way, I added the CSS file

In Function.php

```
function add_theme_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'slider_swiper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/swiper.min.css', array(), false, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'all-min-css-font-awseom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/all.min.css', array(), false, 'all');

function load_archive_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cateogory_archive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/category_archive.css', array(), false, 'all');
}

function load_header_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'header_1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/header_1.css', false, false, 'all');
}

function load_single_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'header_1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/single.css', false, false, 'all');
}


function load_archive_product_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'archive_product_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/archive_product.css', array(), false, 'all');
}

function load_question_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'question', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/question.css', array(), false, 'all');
}

function load_product_page_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'product_page_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/product.css', array(), false, 'all');
}

wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', array (  ), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'swiper-bundle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/swiper-bundle.min.js', array (  ), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_javascript_code', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array (  ), false, true);

}
```

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );

And In single.php File , Call the function of related style ( load_single_style(); )

This Method In All of File is Okay , But in single.php Dont work It,

Comment: You should add reference to your question that shows your example code is mandatory to work. Just trying something and then "not work" and the initial "why?" does not suffice for a good programming question (it should go without saying that you can always edit and improve your contributions here on Stackoverflow). Such would be likely more on topic with a discussion board or a chat session with a support engineer. If you've not made your changes to Wordpress based on references, checkout existing Q&A that is in context and compare the different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you've already appointed the enqueue name header_1 for header_1.css.

```
 function load_header_style(){
      wp_enqueue_style( 'header_1', 
  get_template_directory_uri() . 
  '/css/header_1.css', false, false, 'all');
 }
```

Try just change the enqueue name for single.css to another name. Example:

```
 function load_single_style(){
       wp_enqueue_style( 'single_page', 
   get_template_directory_uri() . 
   '/css/single.css', false, false, 'all');
}
```

Comment: No , I Change the enqueue Name , But the problem was not solved ، Thank